# TERASOLUNA Server Framework for Java（Web版）チュートリアルでエラーがでています。

Tags: java, database

こんにちは。

現在、業務研修でTERASOLUNA Server Framework for Javaのチュートリアルの構築作業を行っています。

[TERASOLUNA Server Framework for Java（Web版）チュートリアル](http://terasoluna.osdn.jp/tutorial/server-web/Document/WebTutorial.html)

基本的なログオン機能を構築しているのですが、
 2.6 登録処理の動作確認の箇所で登録情報の入力をして登録ボタンを押すと
　「エラーが発生しました。」のレスポンスが返ってきて原因が特定できず困っています。

仕様ツールの環境設定は同じものでそろえていますが、

H2databaseが反映されていない。
ビジネスロジックは登録機能がきちんと動いていない等が
考えられます。

基本的に設定ファイル、コード等はチュートリアルの流れに従って、確認して漏れはないと思われますが何かこの時点でエラー画面が返ってきてしまうのに考えられる要因はありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

**以下追記**

---

以下がsqlmapコードになります。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap
            PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN"
            "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">
<!-- SqlMap定義 -->
<sqlMap namespace="user">

<!-- 指定したIDのを取得する -->
    <select id="getUser"
            parameterClass="jp.terasoluna.thin.tutorial.web.usermanager.dto.InsertInput"
            resultClass="jp.terasoluna.thin.tutorial.web.usermanager.vo.SelectUserOutput">
        SELECT ID, NAME, AGE, BIRTH FROM USERLIST WHERE ID = #id#
    </select>

    <!-- ユーザを挿入する -->
    <insert id="insertUser"
        parameterClass="jp.terasoluna.thin.tutorial.web.usermanager.dto.InsertInput">
        INSERT INTO USERLIST (
        ID,
        NAME,
        AGE,
        BIRTH
        )VALUES(
        #id#,
        #name#,
        #age#,
        #birth#)
    </insert>




<!-- 設定例
  <select id="selectUsers"
          resultClass="jp.terasoluna.sample.user.dao.SelectUsersOutput">
    SELECT
        ID AS "userId",
        NAME AS "userName"
    FROM
        USERLIST
  </select>

  <select id="getUserCount"
          parameterClass="jp.terasoluna.sample.user.dao.GetUserCountInput"
          resultClass="jp.terasoluna.sample.user.dao.GetUserCountOutput">
    SELECT
        COUNT (*) AS userCount
    FROM
        USERLIST
    WHERE
        ID = #userId#
  </select>

  <insert id="insertUser"
          parameterClass="jp.terasoluna.sample.user.dao.InsertUserInput">
    INSERT INTO USERLIST (
        ID,
        NAME
    )
    VALUES (
        #userId#,
        #userName#
    )
  </insert>

  <update id="updateUser"
          parameterClass="jp.terasoluna.sample.user.dao.UpdateUserInput">
    UPDATE USERLIST
    SET
        NAME = #userName#
    WHERE
        ID = #userId#
  </update>

  <delete id="deleteUser"
          parameterClass="jp.terasoluna.sample.user.dao.DeleteUserInput">
    DELETE FROM
        USERLIST
    WHERE
        ID = #userId#
  </delete>
-->
</sqlMap>
```

Comment: それだけの情報では原因を特定できません。ログをチェックして下さい。

Comment: [2017/08/23 15:55:10][ERROR][DefaultExceptionHandler] 例外ハンドラが例外を検知しました
com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: There is no statement named getUser in this SqlMap.

Comment: すみません。原因となりうるエラーログはこちらになると思われるのですが、 getUserが SqlMap内に見当たらないという内容ですが、getUser関するにSQL文は記述はしてあると確認できています。

Comment: SqlMapの設定ファイルを質問の本文に追記して下さい。

Comment: 追記しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.getUser`で参照すべき個所を`getUser`で参照しているのではないでしょうか。

[このページ](http://terasoluna.osdn.jp/tutorial/server-web/Document/WebTutorial_2.6.4.html)を読むと、以下のような記述がありますが、

> SQLMap定義ファイルにて、以下のようにuseStatementNamespaces属性に“true”が指定されている場合は、 DAOでSQLIDを指定する際に、SQL設定ファイルの名前空間を付与する必要がある。
>
> ・SQL設定ファイル
>
> ```
> <sqlMap namespace="user">
>
>     <!-- 指定したIDのを取得する -->
>     <select id="getUser"
>     　…
> ```
>
> ・SQLIDの指定例
>
> ```
> queryDAO.executeForObject("user.getUser", param, SelectUserOutput.class);
> ```

これに対して、次のような実装になっているために、エラーが出ているのではないかと思います。

```
queryDAO.executeForObject("getUser", param, SelectUserOutput.class);
```

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。名前空間の設定はtureにしていたので、executeForObjectを実行する際のgetuser sql idのuser指定をしていなかったということですね。insertuser sql id も同様でした。

Comment: 解決したら、チェックマークのリンクをクリックして解決済みにして下さい～。